# How to open .Desktop file in Windows

Tags: linux

I'm a Designer by profession, I need to know how can i open a .Desktop extension file in  windows 7, the file contains info on creating icons for Linux to be used for a software that runs on Linux Operating system.

Comment: With a text editor?

Answer (score 3):

Any text editor will do:

```
$ file Skyrim\ \(SKSE\).desktop 
Skyrim (SKSE).desktop: ASCII text
```

as the contents are just text

```
$ cat Skyrim\ \(SKSE\).desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Skyrim (SKSE)
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/games/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Skyrim (SKSE)" %F
Icon=/usr/share/games/playonlinux/etc/playonlinux.png
Name[fr_FR]=Skyrim (SKSE)
```

On windows 7 you can use tools such as `notepad` or `wordpad` or anything that can open text files.